# Bind List of Checkboxes to Edit View on MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> **Edit in Controller**

Create is ok, but cant bind the selected values from  db to the edit View.. it show the checkboxes but they are empty. I know just a little thing is wrong here, need a sharp eye to catch it. It will help me alot. Thnx

```
[AuthorizeRoles(RoleNames.CanEditCustomer)]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
     if (id == null)
     {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     }

     var customer = customerManager.Get(id);      
     if (customer == null)
     {
        return HttpNotFound();
     }

     var vm = new CustomerViewModel();
     vm.GetCustomerTypeViewModel(new List<CustomerTypeViewModel>(), customerTypeManager.GetAll());
     return View(vm);
}
```

> **Edit View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @{
       for (int i = 0; i < Model.GetCustomerType.Count(); i++)
       {
            <div class="col-md-10">                       
               @Html.Label(Model.GetCustomerType[i].Description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
               @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.GetCustomerType[i].Selected)
               @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GetCustomerType[i].Id)
               @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GetCustomerType[i].Description)
            </div>
       }
    }
</div>
```

> **ViewModel**

```
public List<CustomerTypeViewModel> GetCustomerType { get; set; }
public void GetCustomerTypeViewModel(IEnumerable<CustomerTypeViewModel> selected, IEnumerable<CustomerTypeViewModel> all)
{
     foreach (var item in all)
     {
         GetCustomerType.Add(item);
     }

     foreach (var item in selected)
     {
         GetCustomerType.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Description == item.Description).Selected = true;
     }
}
```

> **Manager**

```
private void InsertOrUpdateCustomerTypes(int? customerId, IEnumerable<int?> customerTypeIds)
{
    var query = "Delete FROM CustomerCheckedType WHERE customerId = @customerId";
    context.Execute(query, new { customerId });
    query = "INSERT INTO CustomerCheckedType (customerId, customerTypeId) VALUES (@customerId, @customerTypeId)";

    foreach (var customerTypeId in customerTypeIds)
    {
        context.Execute(query, new { customerId, customerTypeId });
    }
}
```

**Any help will be highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

Your `Edit View` should be as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @{
       for (int i = 0; i < Model.GetCustomerType.Count(); i++)
       {
            <div class="col-md-10">                       
               @Html.Label(Model.GetCustomerType[i].Description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

               <input type="checkbox" name="selectedCustomerTypes" value="@Model.GetCustomerType[i].Id"
                                     @if (Model.GetCustomerType[i].Selected)
                                      {
                                          <text> Checked</text>
                                      }/>
               @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GetCustomerType[i].Id)
               @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GetCustomerType[i].Description)
            </div>
       }
    }
</div>
```

> This is what I usually do to handle check-boxes

Comment: Problem is in the query, not in the view. Please check your query that pulling data from the database for the edit view.

Comment: public CustomerTypeViewModel GetCustomerType(int? id)
        {
            var query = "SELECT * FROM CustomerType where  Id = @id";
            return context.GetObject<CustomerTypeViewModel>(query, new { Id = id });
        }